# What is meant by 'a perfect dipole'?

Tags: electrostatics, terminology, dipole

**Question**

What is meant by a perfect (electric) dipole?

**Additional information**

I came across the term in this question [Force from point charge on perfect dipole](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21223/force-from-point-charge-on-perfect-dipole)  and also in a textbook (which does not explain what it is).

It would be my assumption that a perfect dipole is one of neglible extent so that the force on each charge can be approximated by the force at the centre, but I am unsure and have no source to back it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with John in the comments above. In my knowledge, I haven't come across 'Perfect Dipole' as a defined physics term, but later it dawned upon me, in accordance with the context above, what differentiates a Physical Dipole from a $Perfect$ Dipole is, the Physical dipole consists of two equal and opposite charges $(+/-)Q$, separated by a finite, and well defined distance, $d$.

On the other hand, the $perfect$ dipole is a $model$ (or an approximation) for the physical dipole, where we consider situations like, $d$ $\rightarrow$ $0$. This may be useful when we calculate the dipole (or measure the electric field, $E$, or the potential, $V$) at distances, $k$, where $k>>d$, hence, as a result, we can simplify our equations for $E(k,t)$ and $V(k,t)$ and maybe in some other cases as well.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -2):

perfect dipoles means forces at center of dipole is zero

Comment: Any evidence/proofs/sources to back this statement up?